# How do I turn off the text tone swoosh when sending text messages?

Tags: iphone

I can turn off all phone sounds, but is there any way I can specifically just turn off the send message sound?

Comment: where, on what?

Comment: the tag says on iPhone.

Comment: Sorry. Should I have specified in the question? I thought the tag would be enough.

Comment: I have turned off only the swoosh sound when sending a text message; however, I can no longer find how I did it before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's not exactly what you might be looking for, if under **Settings / Sounds / Sounds** you set *Text Tone* to *None*, no sound will me made, neither when receiving nor when **sending** a Message.

Answer (score 2):

I turned the default sound to just vibration, which turns off the swoosh sound and put personalized text alert sounds for individual people so I would be able to hear their incoming messages.

Comment: To: user153449 -- YOU are a genius!! That worked perfect! Thank you! :) (i know this was from 4 yrs ago but his answer was perfect).

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn it off, but there's a workaround on [MacRumors forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1332819). It involves accessing the phone system file and deleting the sound file.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is jailbroken, you can remove the following file to remove the sound:

```
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SentMessage.caf
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the sound when receiving text messages and just the disable sent text message sound I had to also delete the file `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Swish.caf` in iOS 8.4.

1. [Jailbreak](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak) to get root access
2. Open Cydia & install MobileTerminal or WhiteTerminal
3. Open your terminal app & switch to root with `su root` (default pass is alpine)
4. `rm /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SentMessage.caf`
5. `rm /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Swish.caf`

Answer (score 0):

I tried what "reflexiv" said

> - Jailbreak to get root access
> - Open Cydia & install MobileTerminal or WhiteTerminal
> - Open your terminal app & switch to root with `su root` (default pass is alpine)
> - `rm /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SentMessage.caf`
> - `rm /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Swish.caf`

To keep the sound when receiving text messages and just the disable sent text message sound I had to also delete the file /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Swish.caf in iOS 8.4.

*Its work perfectly. I'm using iPhone5s iOS 9.0.2 ;)*

**Don't delete the sound file, just move "cut" it to another folder. so u can get it back any time u need it.**

Answer (score 0):

Go to sounds and disable (set text sounds to none/vibration only) text sounds and keyboard tones this should work no need to jailbreak.